# Load different data in different tabs in python flask

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a python web application. I have web page with three tabs. I want to show different data in different tab.

I am able to create tabs and tab switching is also happening. I have already tried with static data and it is working.

Should I send all the data when page was loaded first time?

How to send the data only when tab is switched?

Comment: "It is possible to send the data only when tab is switched ?" yes it is. and it is the better way to do it.

Comment: thanks Omar. can you suggest how i can do that, probably any link with example.

Comment: search for AJAX

Comment: @OmarEinea, thanks for the hint, i was able to achieve it with AJAX.